# Show that the depth of water in the tank at any time satisfies the below differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

[image]
[image]

I saw a similar [problem](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math53/tests/08aut-m1sol.pdf) from Standford, but I couldn't figure out how to apply Standford's answer to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The volume $V(t)$ of water in the tank at time $t$ is given by

$$V(t)=\frac{\pi h^3(t)}{3}\,\tan^2(\phi)$$

Hence, the rate of change in $V(t)$, $\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=\overbrace{k}^{\text{Inward flow rate}}-\overbrace{\alpha \sqrt{h(t)}}^{\text{Outward flow rate}}$, is given by

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dV(t)}{dt}&=\pi h^2(t)\tan^2(\phi)\frac{dh(t)}{dt}\\\\
&=k-\alpha \sqrt {h(t)}
\end{align}$$

whereupon solving for $\frac{dh(t)}{dt}$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{dh(t)}{dt}=\frac{k-\alpha \sqrt{h(t)}}{\pi h^2(t)\tan^2(\phi)}}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: How did you know that V(t)=(πh^3(t)/3)(tan^2(ϕ))?

Comment: The volume can be found by integrating $\int_0^h \pi^2 r^2(\tilde h)\,d\tilde h=\int_0^h \pi (\tilde h \tan(\phi))^2\,d\tilde h$ where we used $r=h\tan(\phi)$